# React Native `Formdata` is not able to send data to backend due to {_parts}

Tags: react-native, multipartform-data

[image]i don't know why in `react native` `formData` use to send data in {_parts} and that gives response for data field as this field is required with 400 error...

> in backend it not able to receive in {_parts}

have anyone go through this issue please let me know I am stuck in this since 1week.. but working fine in web application using `formData` it simply goes like the given image

Answer (score 0):

It works like that so its normal

React Native Form Data is used to send form data which also includes files so when using with FormData, set header 'Content-Type':'multipart/formdata' and i think you backend should understand this.

Refer the link below which is article to how send data in react native which also has backend code in Node and Express.

[This Link](https://www.reactnativeschool.com/how-to-upload-images-from-react-native)

This Should get you idea clear.

Comment: backend is laravel and i need to send other datas like email, name not only image but the think is {_parts doesnt accept it in backend...so what should i do please tell me?